# UpdatePanel and ModalPopup Extender

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have my form designed as

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="xyz">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

          'Gridview with edit/delete - opens detailsview(edit template) with data 
           for editing

         </ContentTemplate>                
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

           'Hyperlink to open detailsview(insert template) for inserting records

         </ContentTemplate>                
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="xyz1">
'Ajax modal popup extender control
</asp:Panel>
```

It works perfectly when i click update, insert alternately, 
but when i click insert hyperlink (which is outside gridview) and close/cancel popup without any insert and then again click insert it doesn't call insert_onclick event. It works if i click some other button and click this button. What could be causing this issue and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. In insert hyperlink i set CausesValidation = False and it is working . I have required field validators in popup and they where causing issue.